# Не работает алгоритм минимакса

Tags: c++

Приветствуют. Пишу алгоритм Минимакс для игры 5 в ряд и столкнулся с проблемой, что мой алгоритм видимо не работает. Пробежавшись в отладчике, увидел что Evaluation не изменяется, не понимаю почему так и прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой.
Логика программы заключается в том, что в функции getComputerPosition() ставится символ на пустое место, и далее вызывается сам минимаксный алгоритм, после чего высчитывается оценка и сохраняются координаты лучшего хода.

```
int miniMax(int board[N][N], int depth, bool isMaximising)
{
    int Evaluation = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int computerChar = BLACK;

    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return Evaluation;
    }
    

    if (isMaximising) 
    {
        int Evaluation = std::numeric_limits<int>().min();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == BLANK)
                {
                    board[i][j] = computerChar;
                    score = miniMax(board, depth - 1, userTurn);
                    board[i][j] = BLANK;
                    Evaluation = std::max(Evaluation, score);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    else 
    {
        int Evaluation = std::numeric_limits<int>().max();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == BLANK)
                {
                    board[i][j] = -computerChar;
                    score = miniMax(board, depth - 1, aiTurn);
                    board[i][j] = BLANK;
                    Evaluation = std::min(Evaluation, score);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return Evaluation;
}


std::pair<int, int> getComputerPosition(int board[N][N])
{
    
    int bestScore = 0;
    int tempBestScore;
    int bestXCoordinate;
    int bestYCoordinate;
    int tempBoard[N][N]; // board copy

    int computerChar = BLACK;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            tempBoard[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (tempBoard[i][j] == BLANK)
            {   
                tempBoard[i][j] = computerChar;
                tempBestScore = miniMax(tempBoard, 5, userTurn);
                tempBoard[i][j] = BLANK;
                if (tempBestScore > bestScore)
                {
                    bestScore = tempBestScore;
                    bestXCoordinate = i;
                    bestYCoordinate = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(bestXCoordinate, bestYCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: По беглому взгляду так понимаю все время нуль значение получается?

Comment: Просто в начале мне кажется условия depth == 0 недостаточно поскольку нужно ещё проверить победил ли игрок, компьютер или же вышла ничья и тогда вернуть соответствующее значение, в противном случае продолжить вычисления.

Comment: Не понятно зачем нам эта портянка?  Есть же отладчик.